# Adding data as many as indexPath - Swift

Tags: swift

I draw data from the database, assign the data I have taken to LINKSTRING. The data I have assigned is the link and I am viewing the photos using this link. For example, there are 5 data I have assigned to LINKSTRING how can I assign these 5 data to photos variable. I want to add up to x photos in LINKSTRING. 
**Example**:

```
self.photos = [CustomPhotoModel (imageURL: URL (string: "\ (self.LINKSTRING [0])"), thumbnailImageURL: URL (string: "\ (self.LINKSTRING [0]))"))] self.photos = [CustomPhotoModel (imageURL: URL (string: "\ (self.LINKSTRING [1])"), thumbnailImageURL: URL (string: "\ (self.LINKSTRING [1]))"))]
```

How do I assign variables in the form?

```
import UIKit
import INSPhotoGallery

class CustomModelViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    lazy var photos = [CustomPhotoModel]()
        var LINKSTRING : [String] = [] 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fillWithYORUM()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
    func fillWithYORUM() {
          let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!
          client.connect("...", username: "...", password: "...", database: "...") { success in
          client.execute("SELECT ... FROM ...", completion: { (_ results: ([Any]?)) in
           var gifsa: [String] = []
           for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {
            for row in table {
            for (_, value) in row {
              if let intVal = value as? String {
                                  gifsa.append(String(intVal)) }} }}
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.photos = [CustomPhotoModel(imageURL: URL(string: "\(LINKSTRING)"), thumbnailImageURL: URL(string: "\(LINKSTRING)"))]

            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
            client.disconnect()
           }) } }
}


extension CustomModelViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ExampleCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ExampleCollectionViewCell
        cell.populateWithPhoto(photos[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])

        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return photos.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ExampleCollectionViewCell
        let currentPhoto = photos[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        let galleryPreview = INSPhotosViewController(photos: photos, initialPhoto: currentPhoto, referenceView: cell)

        galleryPreview.referenceViewForPhotoWhenDismissingHandler = { [weak self] photo in
            if let index = self?.photos.firstIndex(where: {$0 === photo}) {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
                let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? ExampleCollectionViewCell
                return cell
            }
            return nil
        }
        present(galleryPreview, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to append the data to your photos array like this:

```
if LINKSTRING.count > 0 {
    for photoUrl in LINKSTRING {
        let data = CustomPhotoModel (imageURL: URL (string: photoUrl), thumbnailImageURL: URL (string: photoUrl)]
        self.photos.append(data)
    }
}
```